# transfer to other table mysql in same database, some field is insert manual, dan delete source data directly

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a problem in sql query

i have 2 table with field as below :

TABLE1

```
id, user_id, produk_id, booking_date, color, qty
```

TABLE2

```
id, order_id, user_id, produk_id, date, color, qty, status
```

i try to transfer data from table 1 to table 2 :

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (user_id, produk_id, color, qty)
SELECT user_id, produk_id, color, qty
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE user_id = '10002'
```

that code is work, when data what i want to insert to TABLE2 is same with data from table1,

the problem is, the data i want inserted is have some different and i need to insert it manually..

for field

```
user_id, produk_id, color, qty  ==>is same with TABLEE1
```

but for Field

```
order_id, date, status   ==> i need to input manually using PHP variable
```

and i want to delete the row from TABLE1 if the data is already transfer to TABLE2

i really not idea to modify that query

is possible do that in once??
Can someone help, what query should I make to get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add all columns to the insert and also add your php variables to the select:

```sql
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (order_id,user_id, date, produk_id, color, qty,status)
SELECT orderIdPHPvar, user_id, datePHPvar, produk_id, color, qty, statusPHPvar
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE user_id = '10002'
```

see this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/67353/1) for a demo on how to do that.

As for the DELETE, you can't do that in the same statement. You will have to do a separate statement for that.

```sql
DELETE FROM TABLE1 
WHERE user_id = '10002'
```